# $\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ are isomorphic as vector spaces but not as fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

This question is from Thomas Hungerford algebra  Pg 241 and I was unable to solve this problem.

> $\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ are isomorphic as vector spaces but not as fields.

If I could prove that $\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ have same degree as fields over $\mathbb{Q}$ then they would be isomorphic but the degree of $\mathbb{C}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is not defined and degree of $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is 2. So, I think I should use some other method.

Also, To disproving that they are not isomorphic as fields I thought of defining f : $\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{Q(i)}$ and obtain some contradiction using f and some elements but failed to do so.

So, Can you help me with both these questions . Just give hints, not complete solutions.

Comment: Consider the cardinality of the two sets.

Comment: For the record, there is no field $\Bbb K$ such that $\Bbb C$ and $\Bbb Q(i)$ are isomorphic as $\Bbb K$-vector spaces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The degrees over $\Bbb Q$ are different. We have $[\Bbb Q(i):\Bbb Q]=2$ with vector space basis $\{1,i\}$ whereas the other degree is infinite: [The field extension $\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{Q}$ is infinite](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1901352/the-field-extension-mathbbc-mathbbq-is-infinite).

Another fact is that $\Bbb C$ is algebraically closed, but $\Bbb Q(i)$ is not.

And as Gae.S. says, $\Bbb C$ and $\Bbb Q(i)$ cannot be isomorphic as vector spaces over a field because of cardinality reasons. Is there a typo? The "usual" homework is:

"$\Bbb Q(i)$ and $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{2})$ are isomorphic vector spaces, but not isomorphic fields."

Comment: They cannot even be isomorphic as groups for that matter.

Comment: @DietrichBurde So, there is a typo . They can't be even isomorphic as vector spaces as diferrence in cardinality over $\mathbb{Q}$. Is it fine